# Unable to find Wordpress toolkit in cPanel. Wordpress Manager is deprecated

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

I am new to `wordpress` and loged in to my `cPanel` account and getting the message.

[image: Wordpress Manager is deprecated]

After research I found that I have to upgrade to `wordpress toolkit`.

But, `Wordpress toolkit` is not showing anywhere on `cPanel`. I would login to `Wordpress` admin dashboard.

```
thelearningcenter.pk/wp-login.php
```

Any idea how to do that. I also change the wordpress admin password but still not able to login. Or my hosting company in charge to upgrade? Or I have to find myself?

Any suggestion or recommendation or step by step reference doc/links from you will be appreciated.

Comment: do you have softalucas ?

Comment: Contact your host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, take a full backup on your hosting. Re-download Wordpress after backup. After accessing your server with FTP, upload the existing wp.config.php and wp-content directory into the newly downloaded wordpress. In this way, you can reload the core modules of Wordpress without damaging the content of your website.

Use the instant full backup you have to go back in case of any problem.

I hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://dashboard.cpanelcontrolpanel.com/knowledgebase/10/How-To-Use-cPanel-WordPress-Manager-To-Install-WordPress.html?language=italian) we can read:

> Though still available as an option, the WordPress Manager interface
> is deprecated. Customers can now use WordPress Toolkit to install and
> manage WordPress. The WordPress Manager interface (cPanel >> Home >>
> Applications >> WordPress Manager) allows you to install and manage
> new or existing WordPress® sites within your cPanel interface.

In the order, I would:

- check if you can install the WordPress Toolkit from the WHM Marketplace
- if you have SSH access, install it using the manual way

If it's not installed, and you cannot install it, because no Marketplace or manual installation is possible: contact your host.

If you installed yourself Cpanel on your server, then you should have required access to upgrade it or its dependencies.